# Countries Grouping in c

Tags: c

People in a group are sitting in a group numbered 1 to N. It is known that people of same countries are sitting together.
Output is a single integer denoting no of distinct countries.
Input 
4 (no of test cases)
2 (no of people in group)
1 1 ( in this there are 2 people from diff country)
2
1 3 
7
1 1 2 2 3 3 3
7
7 7 7 7 7 7 7
Output should be
2
Invalid Data
4
1
My program:please tell me where is the error

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
int tcaseno,nopgrp,flag=0;
int arr[1000];
int count=0,i=0,j=0,t=0;
scanf("%d", &tcaseno);
t=tcaseno;
while(t>0)
{
scanf("%d\n", &nopgrp);
for (i = 0; i < nopgrp;i++)
{
scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
}
for (j = 0; j < nopgrp;j++)
{
if(arr[j]==1)
{
    count++;
}
else if(arr[j]==2)
{
 if(arr[j+1]==2)
 {
    count++;
 }  
 else
 {
    flag=1;
 }
}
else if(arr[j]==3)
{
 if((arr[j+1]==3)&&(arr[j+2]==3))
 {
    count++;
 }  
 else
 {
    flag=2;
 }
}
else if(arr[j]==4)
{
 if((arr[j+1]==4)&&(arr[j+2]==4)&&(arr[j+3]==4))
 {
    count++;
 }  
 else
 {
    flag=3;
 }
}
else if(arr[j]==5)
{
 if((arr[j+1]==5)&&(arr[j+2]==5)&&(arr[j+3]==5)&&(arr[j+4]==5))
 {
    count++;
 }
 else
 {
    flag=4;
 }  
}
else if(arr[j]==6)
{
 if((arr[j+1]==6)&&(arr[j+2]==6)&&(arr[j+3]==6)&&(arr[j+4]==6)&&(arr[j+5]==6))
 {
    count++;
 }  
 else
 {
    flag=5;
 }
}
else if(arr[j]==7)
{
 if((arr[j+1]==7)&&(arr[j+2]==7)&&(arr[j+3]==7)&&(arr[j+4]==7)&&(arr[j+5]==7)&&(arr[j+6]==7))
 {
    count++;
 }
 else
 {
    flag=6;
 }  
}
else if(arr[j]==8)
{
 if((arr[j+1]==8)&&(arr[j+2]==8)&&(arr[j+3]==8)&&(arr[j+4]==8)&&(arr[j+5]==8)&&(arr[j+6]==8)&&(arr[j+7]==8))
 {
    count++;
 }
 else 
 {
    flag=7;
 }  
}
else if(arr[j]==9)
{
 if((arr[j+1]==9)&&(arr[j+2]==9)&&(arr[j+3]==9)&&(arr[j+4]==9)&&(arr[j+5]==9)&&(arr[j+6]==9)&&(arr[j+7]==9)&&(arr[j+8]==9))
 {
    count++;
 }
 else
 {
    flag=8;
 }  
}
else if(arr[j]==0)
{
    flag=9;
}
}

if(flag!=0)
{
printf("Invalid Data");
flag=0;
}
else
{
printf("%d\n",count);
count=0;
}
t--;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please ___properly___ indent your code. Machine (Compiler) can read and compile anything, but for humans, it needs to make a little _sense_ while reading a block of text as _code_. When asking question, there was a big orange __How to Format__ box to the right of the text area. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a __[?]__ button giving formatting help. And a preview area  showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: `arr[j+1]` and `arr[j+2]`etc can index data that was not input. On the last iteration of `j` loop they will all index data that was not input.

Comment: Please describe your error.

Comment: invalid input is coming again and again

Comment: i have edited please refresh tha page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if((arr[j+1]==9)&&(arr[j+2]==9)&&(arr[j+3]==9) ...)
```

You can simplify the above code with another `for` loop. Evidently you just want to see how many different numbers there are in the array.

Note that one of the main reasons to use C, or to learn C, is for efficiency. Therefore `int arr[1000]` is somewhat out of place because it allocates 4000 bytes. You may want to streamline that with `malloc`/`free`.

You should use `printf` to tell the user what to input.

I took some guesses on what you are trying achieve.

```
int tcaseno, nopgrp, error;
int count, i;
int *arr;
printf("no_test_cases: ");
scanf("%d", &tcaseno);
while(tcaseno > 0)
{
    error = 0;
    count = 1;
    printf("no_people_in_group: ");
    scanf("%d", &nopgrp);
    if(nopgrp > 0 && nopgrp < 1000)
    {
        arr = malloc(nopgrp * sizeof(int));
        printf("Enter %d numbers: ", nopgrp);
        for(i = 0; i < nopgrp; i++)
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        for(i = 1; i < nopgrp; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i - 1] > arr[i])
                error = 1;
            else if(arr[i - 1] != arr[i])
                count++;
        }
        free(arr);
    }
    else
        error = 1;
    if(error)
        printf("Invalid Data\n");
    else
        printf("Result: %d\n", count);
    tcaseno--;
}
```